# How do I center a twitter bootstrap alert in a row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span4 alert alert-info">My Alert</div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work.  Ideas?

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve me hardcoding widths anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using the default 12 column grid:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4 offset4 alert alert-info">My Alert</div>
</div>
```

See **Offsetting columns** on the [grid system section](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) of the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Best to have your code like so:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="span12">
  <div class="alert alert-info">My Alert</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Then you could set the alert to be:

```
.alert {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Strange, should do the job. Try adding the class "text-center" onto the span12 div.

Comment: you're missing a close quote after span12

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="alert alert-info col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-10">My Alert</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mx-auto` css class
Tested with bootstrap 5

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
   <div class="alert alert-info mx-auto">My Alert</div>
 </div>
</div>
```